# JavaScript return other object if array string matches object property value

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, object

I've an simple array of string ids and object and on initial load I'm mapping this `Ids` with this object and making `checked` property to `true`

```
const Ids = ['743156', '743157']
```

```
[
    {
        "id": "743156",
        "role": "Authorized Redistributor (AR)",
        "checked": true,
        "checkBoxPatched": true
    },
    {
        "id": "743157",
        "role": "System Of Record (SOR)",
        "checked": true,
        "checkBoxPatched": true
    },
    {
        "id": "743158",
        "role": "Authorized Redistributor (AR)",
        "checked": false,
        "checkBoxPatched": true
    },
    {
        "id": "743159",
        "role": "System Of Record (SOR)",
        "checked": false,
        "checkBoxPatched": true
    },
    {
        "id": "743976",
        "role": "Authorized Redistributor (AR)",
        "checked": false,
        "checkBoxPatched": true
    },
]
```

Now, user has the option to update by checking checkboxes making `checked` as true, which might make others `Ids` checked property to true. How can I get the object whose `checked` property is true BUT it shouldn't be initial two objects with checked as true.
So For eg I uncheck checkbox with ID `743156` and check `743158` I should get below two objects and if the user hasn't checked any NEW checkbox it should return me with empty object {} and not initial checked checkboxes with ids `743156 & 743157` with checked true

```
 {
        "id": "743157",
        "role": "System Of Record (SOR)",
        "checked": true,
        "checkBoxPatched": true
    },
    {
        "id": "743158",
        "role": "Authorized Redistributor (AR)",
        "checked": true,
        "checkBoxPatched": true
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us what you tried so far please?

Comment: Why does 743157 appear in the desired output? It doesn't match: "How can I get the object whose checked property is true BUT it shouldn't be initial two objects with checked as true."

Comment: @BenStephens I've the first two Ids checked:true( '743156', '743157'), now I uncheck 743156(make checked as false) and make 743158 checked as true. I'm not touching 743157 its true since inception, hence the desired o/p should be as above. Only condition is I shouldn't get already initial checked values

Comment: But 743157 is one of the initial checked values?

Comment: @BenStephens yes sir ['743156', '743157'] are initial checked values

Comment: Maybe I'm having a comprehension failure, but to me "Only condition is I shouldn't get already initial checked values" along with 743157 being one of the initial checked values means that 743157 shouldn't be in the output.

Comment: @BenStephens Already "initial checked values are exclusive '743156' & '743157 both. Either of it can be in combination with other Ids Like 743157 and 743158 as I mentioned above just for an example

Comment: Okay ... I _think_ I get it. What you want is the list of checked items except in the case where the list of checked ids would have the same values as the initial checked values. i.e. you want a new list of checked values unless nothing has changed from last time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the `same_ids_lists` function is used to check whether there have been any changes in which items are checked. It may not be necessary to sort and copy the list arrays if they would always be in the same order.

```js
const ids = ['743156', '743157'];
const data = [
    {
        "id": "743156",
        "role": "Authorized Redistributor (AR)",
        "checked": true,
        "checkBoxPatched": true
    },
    {
        "id": "743157",
        "role": "System Of Record (SOR)",
        "checked": true,
        "checkBoxPatched": true
    },
    {
        "id": "743158",
        "role": "Authorized Redistributor (AR)",
        "checked": false,
        "checkBoxPatched": true
    },
    {
        "id": "743159",
        "role": "System Of Record (SOR)",
        "checked": false,
        "checkBoxPatched": true
    },
    {
        "id": "743976",
        "role": "Authorized Redistributor (AR)",
        "checked": false,
        "checkBoxPatched": true
    },
];

const same_ids_lists = (list_1, list_2) =>
  [...list_1].sort().join('-') === [...list_2].sort().join('-');

const get_new_checked_if_changed = (data, last_ids) => {
  const checked = data.filter( (item) => item.checked );
  
  const is_unchanged = same_ids_lists(
    checked.map( (item) => item.id ),
    last_ids
  );
  
  return is_unchanged ? false : checked;
};

console.log('When unchanged: ', get_new_checked_if_changed(data, ids));

data[0].checked = false;
data[2].checked = true;

console.log('When changed: ', get_new_checked_if_changed(data, ids));
```

Edit: changed `get_new_checked_if_changed` to return false on unchanged, otherwise unchanged and no checked items would be indistinguishable.

Answer (score 1):

To omit the first two objects having ids of ids array respectively and get the checked values,

```
const data = [
    {
        "id": "743156",
        "role": "Authorized Redistributor (AR)",
        "checked": true,
        "checkBoxPatched": true
    },
    {
        "id": "743157",
        "role": "System Of Record (SOR)",
        "checked": true,
        "checkBoxPatched": true
    },
    {
        "id": "743158",
        "role": "Authorized Redistributor (AR)",
        "checked": false,
        "checkBoxPatched": true
    },
    {
        "id": "743159",
        "role": "System Of Record (SOR)",
        "checked": false,
        "checkBoxPatched": true
    },
    {
        "id": "743976",
        "role": "Authorized Redistributor (AR)",
        "checked": false,
        "checkBoxPatched": true
    }
];

const ids = ["743156", "743157"];
const checkedArr = [];
data.map((d) => {
    if (!ids.includes(d.id) && d.checked === true) {
        checkedArr.push(d);
    }
})

console.log(checkedArr);
```

Comment: This works partially this will always omit the first two objects and give me the other checked objects. If I make first one false and third one true, it doesn't give me second and third, it gives me only third one

Comment: This solution will work according to the ids array, whatever ids you pass in that array will be omitted ! So if you pass the ids of 1st and 3rd one then the code will omit the 1st and 3rd ones and check.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use **filter()** method in JS

```js
const arrObj = [
    {
        "id": "743156",
        "role": "Authorized Redistributor (AR)",
        "checked": true,
        "checkBoxPatched": true
    },
    {
        "id": "743157",
        "role": "System Of Record (SOR)",
        "checked": true,
        "checkBoxPatched": true
    },
    {
        "id": "743158",
        "role": "Authorized Redistributor (AR)",
        "checked": false,
        "checkBoxPatched": true
    },
    {
        "id": "743159",
        "role": "System Of Record (SOR)",
        "checked": false,
        "checkBoxPatched": true
    },
    {
        "id": "743976",
        "role": "Authorized Redistributor (AR)",
        "checked": false,
        "checkBoxPatched": true
    },
]

const filterdData = arrObj.filter((_obj)=> _obj.checked === true);

console.log(filterdData)
```

[Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: No this is not what i want, this is are initial two checked values, kindly have a look at my question

Comment: filter the updated arrObj after user made changes.

Comment: Can you elaborate with an example

Comment: use the filter method after the map method you use to check or uncheck the specific objects with ids. u can chain it if u want map().filter()